# Accessing Localhost on iPhone using MAMP Pro

Tags: php, mysql, iphone, apache, mamp

I have scratched my Head for an hour on this. All Tutorials are outdated, and do not work for me. Even other answers on Stackoverflow are not helpful.

I have an iPhone, iPad, Mac Mini, and a Macbook Pro. All my development is on Macbook pro, using MAMP Pro. I use custom host names.

In system Preferences > Network. My Machines IP Address is 10.0.0.4. So, I am typing 10.0.0.4:80 in iPhone's Safari. I have tried a few different combinations, but none of them seem to work.

But, I am unable to access sites on Macbook's localhost, via my iPhone. This is important for me to speed up development.

Here are the settings in my Mamp.

[image]

[image]

If anyone could explain What needs to be done. I shall be Greatful.

Comment: Might seem silly as I haven't messed with much iphone dev, but I'll assume 10.0.0.4 is not your public IP? So, is the phone joined to the local network or is it running on mobile data?

Comment: Actually, Its the Mac's IP on the Wifi Network. iPhone is joined to the Same WiFi.

Comment: Good deal, I know I have fought a similar battle with a phone not being on the wifi so it couldn't access local network items. Just making sure :)

Comment: Your best option is to try to use the iphone emulators included with xcode. In order to resolve your local domains, you would need to configure local DNS to resolve to your internal ip for the test sites. (normally this is done by changing /etc/hosts, but you wont be able to do that on an iphone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work. Same setup here and it works.
What do you see on your phone when accessing the IP?
When I check your Screenshots, it seems that MAMP isn't running.
**Sure your MAMP is running?** :-)
If so, sure your phone is on the **same subnet**?
Post both IPs. Is there a **firewall** between?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a trailing slash? like: 10.0.0.4/

Also, if you connect your iPhone/iPad to your mac through USB, you can debug easily using the safari web browser.

Comment: Yes. Trailing slash is no help. Secondly, I would really prefer the Network Solution.